# Cannot get (->) r monad to work with SDL2 rendering

Tags: haskell, io, sdl, monads, sdl-2

I have a small working SDL2 sample (a straightforward port of a C++ tutorial) and am trying to refactor the rendering code into using the (->) r monad. Here's the working part of the sample without the refactoring

```
renderClear renderer
renderCopy renderer texture nullPtr nullPtr
renderPresent renderer
```

Make & run - the texture is there. Both

```
renderClear renderer
flip ($) renderer $ do
    copy texture nullPtr nullPtr
renderPresent renderer
```

and

```
renderClear renderer
renderCopy renderer texture nullPtr nullPtr
flip ($) renderer $ do
    present
```

work fine too. Yet

```
renderClear renderer
flip ($) renderer $ do
    copy texture nullPtr nullPtr
    present
```

just draws the black window and that's it. `present` is an alias of `renderPresent` and `copy` is `renderCopy` with first argument shifted to the end. Do it have something to do with these functions working with IO? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you combine it into

```
flip ($) renderer $ do
    copy texture nullPtr nullPtr
    present
```

the whole `do` block is in the `(->) r` monad, and so the actions are not sequenced by `IO` or whatever underlying monad you have, instead using essentially

```
(f >> g) x = g x
```

leaving only `present` in the combination.

The way to fix this, I think, is to use a `ReaderT` monad transformer which knows how to use the underlying monad when sequencing, turning it into something like (you'll need to redefine `copy` and `present` appropriately)

```
flip runReaderT renderer $ do
    copy texture nullPtr nullPtr
    present
```

Comment: I've modified my functions to run in the ReaderT with IO and now it works like a charm. Thank you!